# Cannot see Cloud Watch logs from Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I have created AWS API gateway and connected it to a searchLambda using CDK. So I am sending to API;

GET `/?search=something&criteria=city`

This point is integrated with searchLambda, which should receive search, criteria and all processes should go accordingly to the defined workflow.

The problem is that when am hitting API endpoint, API log is showing:

```
    (e276cbf8-8445-437b-93f7-fab1b32d8a22) Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: 2023-03-01T19:59:11.265Z 9e793aa6-6e64-41e8-8237-b08ee11512be Task timed out after 10.80 seconds. Lambda request id: 9e793aa6-6e64-41e8-8237-b08ee11512be
```

NOTE: timeout hardcoded to 10 sec (prev was smaller 3sec, than increased to 10sec just to see if it will help.)

```
    2023-03-01T16:44:29.503-05:00

    Copy
    INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:18.v5    Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:c869d752e4ae21a3945cfcb3c1ff2beb1f160d7bcec3b0a8ef7caceae73c055f
    INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:18.v5 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:c869d752e4ae21a3945cfcb3c1ff2beb1f160d7bcec3b0a8ef7caceae73c055f

    2023-03-01T16:44:41.491-05:00

    Copy
    START RequestId: 6c70644b-6ceb-4b9a-83f3-b90b36aa6ebd Version: $LATEST
    START RequestId: 6c70644b-6ceb-4b9a-83f3-b90b36aa6ebd Version: $LATEST

    2023-03-01T16:44:41.652-05:00

    Copy
    2023-03-01T21:44:41.652Z 6c70644b-6ceb-4b9a-83f3-b90b36aa6ebd Task timed out after 10.21 seconds

    2023-03-01T21:44:41.652Z 6c70644b-6ceb-4b9a-83f3-b90b36aa6ebd Task timed out after 10.21 seconds

    2023-03-01T16:44:41.652-05:00

    Copy
    END RequestId: 6c70644b-6ceb-4b9a-83f3-b90b36aa6ebd
    END RequestId: 6c70644b-6ceb-4b9a-83f3-b90b36aa6ebd

    2023-03-01T16:44:41.652-05:00

    Copy
    REPORT RequestId: 6c70644b-6ceb-4b9a-83f3-b90b36aa6ebd  Duration: 10208.91 ms   Billed Duration: 10000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 128 MB
```

I have added a console log on top of searchLambda but I cannot see it in Cloud Watch.

Here is my Lambda configuration:

```
    {
        "FunctionName": "SearchFlowStack-searchLambda02D5D642-rXVh6Hop7PM3",
        "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:201682123230:function:SearchFlowStack-searchLambda02D5D642-rXVh6Hop7PM3",
        "Runtime": "nodejs18.x",
        "Role": "arn:aws:iam::201682123230:role/SearchFlowStack-searchLambdaServiceRole4ED34712-1HDDNCA114A09",
        "Handler": "index.handler",
        "CodeSize": 5479738,
        "Description": "",
        "Timeout": 10,
        "MemorySize": 128,
        "LastModified": "2023-03-01T19:57:32.000+0000",
        "CodeSha256": "HCyIEDuPx69arYaP+yKdkfRDmXLrVuiy/BO+AsfteDA=",
        "Version": "$LATEST",
        "VpcConfig": {
            "SubnetIds": [],
            "SecurityGroupIds": [],
            "VpcId": ""
        },
        "Environment": {
            "Variables": {
                "STATE_MACHINE_ARN": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:201682123230:stateMachine:cfnStepFunction-Iz9cXZoGzegj",
                "AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED": "1"
            }
        },
        "TracingConfig": {
            "Mode": "PassThrough"
        },
        "RevisionId": "83cb39a5-4e5e-48ca-a838-cf28344b2e04",
        "State": "Active",
        "LastUpdateStatus": "Successful",
        "PackageType": "Zip",
        "Architectures": [
            "x86_64"
        ]
    }
```

And my Lambda function:

```
import { Lambda, StepFunctions } from 'aws-sdk';
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent } from 'aws-lambda';
import { SearchFlowStack } from '../../infra/SearchFlow';

export const handler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<any> => {
  console.log(`#### Step00. Started!!`)
  const { search, criteria } = event.queryStringParameters || {};

  const stepFunctions = new StepFunctions();
  const lambda = new Lambda();
  const { cfnStepFunction, cfnSearchResultsFunction } = SearchFlowStack;

  // Start the Step Function with the given criteria
  const params = {
    stateMachineArn: cfnStepFunction.attrArn,
    input: JSON.stringify({ searchTerm: search, criteria })
  };
.... ....
```

How to debug this.. any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Please check if the role SearchFlowStack-searchLambdaServiceRole4ED34712-1HDDNCA114A09 has access to write to CloudWatch logs

Comment: @Sri When I SearchFlowStack-searchLambda in AWS gui console >> Permision>>Amazon Cloud Watch Logs:
Allow: logs:CreateLogGroup
Allow: logs:CreateLogStream
Allow: logs:PutLogEvents

Comment: `import { SearchFlowStack } from '../../infra/SearchFlow';` may be causing a failure to initialise the function, so the body is never executed. When you use the 'Test' functionality in the lambda console, what result does it give you?

Comment: as @shnhndly mentioned check your import statement. and maybe try to start with simple hello-world lambda code to make sure logs are written and found in cloudwatch